# Want to get the data of current login user in laravel using foreign key relationship but gives duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to get the data of current login user using laravel and mysql but I am getting the result duplicate rows of stored in data base.
I have three tables. users table containing id as primary key, education table containing user_id as foreign key, the primary key of users table and also a field research_area. The third table is publications table which is also containing user_id as foreign key. Now I am trying to get the all publications of current login user with title, publication year and research area. My code is working but it gives me all the result of stored data in tables. My code is given here.

Controller code is PdfController.php

```
   <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use DB;
    use PDF;
    use Auth;

    class PdfController extends Controller
    {
        public function publicationpdf()
            {
                $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $data['data'] = DB::table('users')
                    ->join('publications', 'users.id', '=', 'publications.user_id')
                    ->join('education', 'users.id', '=', 'education.user_id')
                    ->select('users.id','publications.*','education.research_area')
->where('users.id',$user_id)
                    ->get();
                if(count ($data)>0){
                    return view('pdf/publicationpdf',$data);
                }
                else
                {
                    return view('pdf/publicationpdf');
                }
     }
```

My view is publicationpdf.blade.php and its code is given here.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container"><br>


    <h4>Name: {{ Auth::user()->tname }}</h4>



    <div class="text-center">
        <h3>Publications Details</h3>
    </div><br/>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Publication Title
            </th>
            <th>Research Area</th>
            <th>Publication Year</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach($data as $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$value->title}}</td>

            <td>{{$value->research_area}}</td>

            <td>{{$value->year}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach

    </table>


</div>

@endsection
```

and my route is here.

```
Route::get('pdf/publicationpdf','PdfController@publicationpdf');
```

I dont know how to get the all publications of login user just one time every row, but it gives me duplicate rows, I means three copies of one row, It does not show any error but returning the duplicate data of  user. Please help. Thank in advance

Picture is here
[image: result of above running view]

My tables are given Here.
publications table.
[image: publications table]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
You should add where user table has id=logged in user id.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use PDF;
use Auth;

class PdfController extends Controller
{
    public function publicationpdf()
        {
            $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $data['data'] = DB::table('users')
                ->join('publications', 'users.id', '=', 'publications.user_id')
                ->join('education', 'users.id', '=', 'education.user_id')
                ->select('users.id','publications.*','education.research_area')
                ->where('users.id',$user_id) // else it will get all rows
                ->get();
            if(count ($data)>0){
                return view('pdf/publicationpdf',$data)->with($user_id);
            }
            else
            {
                return view('pdf/publicationpdf');
            }
 }
```

Comment: I have only two record of current login user in database but it gives me 6 rows I means three time one row. I want just one time

Comment: hi too, yes I tried where method but I am getting 6 rows but there is only two rows of same login user in database.

Comment: Can you post the query using DB::table('users')
                ->join('publications', 'users.id', '=', 'publications.user_id')
                ->join('education', 'users.id', '=', 'education.user_id')
                ->select('users.id','publications.*','education.research_area')
                ->where('users.id',$user_id)->toSql();

Comment: Bro adding toSql() instead of get() at end and echoing it will give you the sql query if you are not using debugbar

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\prolearning\resources\views\pdf\publicationpdf.blade.php)

Comment: echo DB::table('users') ->join('publications', 'users.id', '=', 'publications.user_id') ->join('education', 'users.id', '=', 'education.user_id') ->select('users.id','publications.*','education.research_area') ->where('users.id',$user_id)->toSql(); die;

Comment: I don't want to echo, I want to print it in view.

Comment: We will echo just for debug purposes. You will get your query this way. Try running that query directly in phpmyadmin and try editing it.

Answer (score 0):

How many rows you have in your education table for that particular user? The result you are getting is normal because you have multiple records in your child tables publication or education.

Comment: In my child table there are only two rows for particular user.

Comment: What you are getting if you are trying this?

 DB::table('publications')                  
                    
->where('users.id',$user_id)
                    ->get();

Comment: I am getting more than two rows, while I have two rows in publications table for current login user.

Comment: And did you get the same result when you run your query directly in phpmyadmin?

Comment: I can not run directly, I dont know how to run

Comment: Click SQL tab in your phpmyadmin and paste this query in textarea and run 
`select * from publications where publications.user_id = $id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183057/discussion-between-osama-alvi-and-irfan-khan).